# I have a problem with Datatable when active scrollX with column filter (search)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, datatable

I have a problem with Datatable when active scrollX with column filter (search)
i tried hard but nothing

image 1 : the search work fine if scrollx is disabled

[image: the search work fine if scrollx is disabled]

image 2 : but the table is not scrollable from right to left or from left to right

[image: but the table is not scrollable from right to left or from left to right]

image 3 : when i active scrollX

[image: when i active scrollx]

image 4 : column filter (search) is disabled and the table header change to that
[image: column filter (search) is disabled and the table header change to that]

image 5 : and the table scroll work fine .. !!!

[image: and the table scroll work fine .. !!!]

image 6 : i want to active scrollX , column filter work fine , and change the table header to be like in the image

[image: i want to active scrollX , column filter work fine , and change the table header to be like in the image]

the code :

```
<script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                // Initialize DataTable
                                var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                                    // Enable searching
                                    searching: true,
                                    // // Enable horizontal scrolling
                                    // scrollX: true,
                                    // fixedHeader: true,
                                    // Enable export buttons
                                    dom: '<"dt-top-container"<l><"dt-center-in-div"B><f>r>t<ip>',
                                    //dom: 'Blfrtip',
                                    // dom: '<"dt-top-container"<"dt-left"<l>><"dt-center-in-div"B><"dt-right"f>>t<ip>',
                                    buttons: [{
                                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                        text: 'XLSX',
                                        title: $('title').text() + ' - ' + (new Date()).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                                            day: '2-digit',
                                            month: '2-digit',
                                            year: 'numeric',
                                            hour: '2-digit',
                                            minute: '2-digit'
                                        }).replace(/[\/\,\:]/g, '-'),
                                        filename: $('title').text() + '-' + (new Date()).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                                            day: '2-digit',
                                            month: '2-digit',
                                            year: 'numeric',
                                            hour: '2-digit',
                                            minute: '2-digit'
                                        }).replace(/[\/\,\:]/g, '-') + '.xlsx',
                                        exportOptions: {
                                            orthogonal: 'export',
                                            columns: ':not(:eq(4))'
                                        },
                                        customize: function (xlsx) {
                                            var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                                            $('row c[r^="C"]', sheet).attr('s', '0');
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        extend: 'copyHtml5',
                                        text: 'Copy',
                                        exportOptions: {
                                            columns: ':visible'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        extend: 'csvHtml5',
                                        text: 'CSV',
                                        fieldSeparator: ',',
                                        decimalSeparator: '.',
                                        title: $('title').text(),
                                        filename: $('title').text() + '-' + (new Date()).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                                            day: '2-digit',
                                            month: '2-digit',
                                            year: 'numeric',
                                            hour: '2-digit',
                                            minute: '2-digit'
                                        }).replace(/[\/\,\:]/g, '-'),
                                        charset: 'utf-8',
                                        exportOptions: {
                                            columns: ':visible'
                                        }
                                    },
                                        // {
                                        //     extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                        //     text: 'PDF',
                                        //     charset: 'utf-8',
                                        //     title: $('title').text(),
                                        //     filename: $('title').text() + '-' + (new Date()).toLocaleString('en-US', {
                                        //         day: '2-digit',
                                        //         month: '2-digit',
                                        //         year: 'numeric',
                                        //         hour: '2-digit',
                                        //         minute: '2-digit'
                                        //     }).replace(/[\/\,\:]/g, '-'),
                                        //     orientation: 'portrait',
                                        //     pageSize: 'A4',
                                        //     exportOptions: {
                                        //         columns: ':visible'
                                        //     }
                                        // }
                                    ],
                                    // Add length menu options
                                    lengthMenu: [
                                        [25, 50, 100, -1],
                                        [25, 50, 100, "All"]
                                    ],
                                    // Set default page length
                                    pageLength: 25,


                                    "language": {
                                        "searchPlaceholder": "Search ...",
                                        "decimal": "",
                                        "emptyTable": "No Data..!!!",
                                        "info": "Show feom _START_ to _END_ from _TOTAL_",
                                        "infoEmpty": "No such data",
                                        "infoFiltered": "( Total _MAX_ )",
                                        "infoPostFix": "",
                                        "thousands": ",",
                                        "lengthMenu": "_MENU_",
                                        "loadingRecords": "Loading ...",
                                        "processing": "Processing ...",
                                        "search": "Search : ",
                                        "zeroRecords": "No result",
                                        "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ Per Page",
                                        "paginate": {
                                            "first": '>>',
                                            "last": '<<',
                                            "next": '>',
                                            "previous": '<'

                                        },
                                        "aria": {
                                            "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                                            "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                // Define array of column indexes that are searchable
                                var searchableColumns = [1, 2, 3]; 

                                // Add input fields for each searchable column
                                $('#dataTable thead th').each(function (index) {
                                    if (searchableColumns.includes(index)) {
                                        var title = $(this).text();
                                        $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for ' + title +
                                            '">');
                                    }
                                });

                                // Apply input field search to each searchable column
                                table.columns().every(function (index) {
                                    if (searchableColumns.includes(index)) {
                                        var that = this;
                                        $('input', this.header()).on('keyup change clear', function () {
                                            if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                                                that.search(this.value).draw();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });

                                // Apply global search
                                $('#global_filter').on('keyup change clear', function () {
                                    table.search(this.value).draw();
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

you can try the code

[https://jsfiddle.net/BakBaka7a/absj38yd](https://jsfiddle.net/BakBaka7a/absj38yd/)

Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need filter fields for all columns?

Comment: for 1st and last columns , i don't need filters

Comment: `// Add input fields for each searchable column` Check the code block below this comment. You're adding these filter fields explicitly. Try commenting out the part from `// Define array of column indexes that are searchable` till `// Apply global search`